# POSTing to a collection association using Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, spring-data-rest

I am have difficulty creating a collection association to which I can POST.
I have two entities, Device and Group, having a Many to Many relationship. such that a Device may be in zero or more groups and a Group may contain zero or more Devices.

I can create new Device and Group entities by POSTing to /api/devices and /api/groups/. From my reading of the docs a Device in devices collection should have a RestResource that represents the collection of groups that the device is a member of (ie. /api/devices/{deviceId}/groups. This is an "association resource" and as it is an instance of `Set<Group>` I would have thought that it was regarded as a collection association. I can get and PUT `uri-list`s to this association, but when I post to it I get a 404.

The list could become quite large and I would like to be able to post a new link to the collection association, without having to download the whole thing modify it and `PUT` it back.

The [documenation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) says that this should be supported, but I am having no luck.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

These Domain Classes are defined as:

```
@Entity
public class Device {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Group.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Group> groups;

    // getters, setters
}
```

and,

```
@Entity(name="device_groups")
public class Group {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
    private Set<Device> devices;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Each one has a repository declared:

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Device, Long> {
}

public interface GroupRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Group, Long> {        
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make use of PATCH, that way you don't have fetch existing collection. Just call PATCH with new link and existing collection gets updated. For example:

Add a new link (device) to a collection:

```
curl -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/app/device/1" http://localhost:8080/app/group/87/devices
```

Add multiple devices to an existing collection:

```
curl -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "
http://localhost:8080/app/device/2
http://localhost:8080/app/device/3" http://localhost:8080/app/group/87/devices
```

Comment: Thanks that works well. I have also found that I can DELETE an individual entry from the collection by deleting (for example) http://localhost:8080/app/group/87/devices/3. However, there is currently one big caveat to that the relationship must be owned by the Group. But that is just JPA for you.

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to do this with `application/json` and what would be the syntax?

Comment: I know this is old but thank you very much for this answer, you've helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PUT request. Good examples, written with Spring Data REST are:

Spring Pet Clinck project

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-boot-petclinic-api)
- [Description](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/10/exposing-spring-data-repositories-over-rest.html)

A Spring Data REST Primer

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/behrangsa-examples/spring-data-rest/tree/example/spring-data-rest-primer)
- [Description](http://blog.behrang.org/java/2018/01/21/a-spring-data-rest-primer.html)